# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in php code

Tags: php

Why `$results` are NULL, where I did wrong ?

I'm getting error in `$rows = $result->fetch_assoc();`

```
class User{

    public $user_name;
    protected $_user_id;
    protected $_user_pwd;
    public $user_email;
    protected $_create_date;

    public  function selectUsers(){

        $db = Database::getInstance();
        $mysqli = $db->getConnection();

        $query = 'select * from tblusers';
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);

        if($result->num_rows)
        {
            $rows = $result->fetch_assoc();
            return $rows['$user_name'];
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are trying to return `return $rows['$user_name'];` you can't use it like ['$user_name'] you have to instead use `$rows[$this->user_name];` or if you want to return all user then you have to `return $rows;` instead

**UPDATE**

i see one more problem it your code as you are selecting many rows with this `$rows = $result->fetch_assoc();` you got inside `$rows` multidimensional array so you should make loop over it like this

```
echo "All Rows: <br>";
var_dump($rows); //to see how is inside
echo "<br>";

foreach($rows as $row){
     var_dump( $row ); //to see how is inside
}
```

so there is no item `$rows['name']` in `$rows` but instead `$rows[0]['name']`

Comment: Thanks. I fixed that. Now I got problem in if statement.Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: try to check your mysql connection if its ok, `var_dump($mysqli)` what you see as dump ?

Comment: object(mysqli)#3 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(1) ["client_info"]=> string(6) "5.5.46" ["client_version"]=> int(50546) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(5) ["host_info"]=> string(25) "Localhost via UNIX socket" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(23) "5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1" ["server_version"]=> int(50544) ["stat"]=> string(140) "Uptime: 2762737 Threads: 1 Questions: 40463 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 124 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 117 Queries per second.

Comment: avg: 0.014" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(1718) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) } 
Notice: Undefined index: in /var/www/html/wh/lib/class.User.inc on line 22

Comment: Ok i got your second problem see my answer after **UPDATE**